# BOOT_COMPLETED action works on one device but not another

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I have been developing a android application for a client on a HTC Desire HD ( Android 2.2) The app makes use of the action BOOT_COMPLETED to automatically start the application on the phones start. This all works fine on the HTC.

The client has said however, that the phone that he wants to app to run on is a Alcatel onetouch|983 ( Android 2.3.7 ).

I have installed the app on this phone, but when I restart the device the application won't start.

When debugging on the Alcatel I can fire the BOOT_COMPLETED action using the adb shell and the reciever class  recognises the action fine and fires the appropriate code. But it never fires when the phone starts.

**My XML manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".FloReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >

                <!-- higher priority than native messaging app -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**My Reciever Class**

```
public class FloReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public static final String SMS_RECEIVED ="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    public static final String BOOT_COMPLETE = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
            if (BOOT_COMPLETE.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Activity_PinEntry.ShowScreenLock(context);
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ReceiverService.class));
        }
        }
}
```

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated, I'm really scratching my head here.

Thanks in advance, Adam.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. and I solved it by transfering the application into the telephone instead of SD memory card. Alcatel is always installing applications to SD card even if you define the installation directory as telephone.